# "glad to find you" or "glad to found you"

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

At the end of an email to a stranger:

> Glad to **find** you!

or

> Glad to **found** you!

Which one is grammatically correct? *Find* or *found*?

Comment: This phrase seems fairly strange to me. What are you hoping to communicate? What is the situation?

Comment: I have met a stranger who is helping me out. And after our chit chat, I wanna say... I'm so glad to find him.

Comment: I see. In that case “I’m glad to have found you” is correct, and “Glad I found you” is a more common/colloquial way of saying the same.

Answer (score 5):

The second:

> *Glad to found you

is incorrect in any case. The first may be correct, depending on what you're trying to say.

> Glad to find you!

is something you might say at the beginning of a letter or meeting. It implies that you have just found the person and are just starting the relationship. It sounds like you're leading up to something.

On the other hand,

> Glad to **have** found you!

or

> Glad I found you!

is something you might say any time; either at the beginning or the end of the letter; it can mean the same as the above, or it can imply that you've already received a benefit and are saying "thanks, goodbye."

So, for example:

> Hi. Can you help me? I'm bleeding!
>
> Don't worry; I'm a doctor. What seems to be the problem?
>
> A doctor? Boy, am I **glad to find you**. I'm not sure what bit me, but it's bleeding a lot. Can I just put a bandage on it?
>
> No;from the bite marks it looks like it might have been a werewolf. You need to light a candle and wave a silver dagger over the wound. Otherwise you will suffer a terrible curse.
>
> Really? I didn't know that! Boy, I'm **glad I found you**--I hate curses. I'll go do that right away!

Answer (score 1):

You technically have two different verbs in your examples:

> [Find](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/find?s=t) - To locate, obtain, or recover, by search, effort, or luck
>   [Found](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/found?s=t) - (Second word) to set up or establish on a firm basis or for enduring existence

As it happens, the past tense of **to find**  *also* is **found**, and the source perhaps of some confusion here.  When you put the "to" in front of "found" that way, it becomes the infinitive form of the second definition, which you almost certainly do not mean here.

The version you are looking for, assuming you have been searching for someone is the first

> *Glad to find you!*

But more frequently you may hear either of these variations, which are slightly more idiomatic

> *Glad I found you.*
>   *[I'm] Glad to have found you.*

In both cases, you use the first verb, **to find** but in the past tense.

You might use the second verb, **to found**, when talking about creating something. Such as in the following sentence:

> *Mark and Sue were eager **to found**  Two Friends Building Websites INC. because it meant they could quit their boring retail jobs and make money doing what they loved.*

<sub>Hope that helps</sub>